# Divergent series with positive elements

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have an infinite and divergent series $\sum a_n$ with non negative terms and i want to show that for any bijection $\varphi$ the rearranged series $\sum a_{\varphi (n)}$ also diverges. How could i do this?

My thoughts:
Since there are non negative terms in the rearranged series, its sequence of partial sums $s_n$ must be increasing monotonously and i would only need to demonstrate that it is unbounded in order to show the series divergence but i dont know how to take this last step.

Comment: Hint: any rearrangement of an absolutely convergent series converges (to the same sum).

Comment: Or maybe do this: any partial sum of one series is less than some partial sum of the other series.